# Reasons for memory error. Numpy division by standard deviation

Tags: python, numpy, memory

I'm trying to normalize my training and test set for MNIST dataset. Here's my code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

prediction = pd.read_csv("sample_submission.csv")
test_csv = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
train_csv = pd.read_csv("train.csv")

train = train_csv.values.T  # turn train set data frame to numpy array
test = test_csv.values.T
y_values = train[[0], :]  # bring y values  [3,1,4,6,2,0,...]
train = train[1:, :]

y = np.zeros((10, y_values.shape[1]))
for i in range(y_values.shape[1]):
    y[y_values[0][i]][i] = 1  # one-hot encoding

# scaling data set values to range (0,1)
train = np.divide(train, np.std(train))
test = np.divide(test, np.std(test))
```

everything seems to be working except that it gives me memory error on the last part where I try to divide the test set with its standard deviation.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/falco/PycharmProjects/Digit-Recognizer/main.py", line 26, in <module>
    test = np.divide(test, np.std(test))
  File "C:\Users\falco\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 3242, in std
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\falco\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py", line 140, in _std
    keepdims=keepdims)
  File "C:\Users\falco\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py", line 117, in _var
    x = asanyarray(arr - arrmean)
MemoryError
```

Any help/ideas on why this is happening would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The error is in `np.std(test)`.  Tell us about `test`.  Is it a `ndarray`?  shape?  dtype?

Comment: On a side note, you should use the same transformation for both training and test data, i.e. not dividing each set by its individual stddev but instead divide both by the training stddev (this won't resolve your error though).

Comment: Your array is apparently eating up more than half your available memory. You could either try to use a smaller array, or perhaps change the datatype (e.g. float64 to float32). Of course, your standard deviation is incorrect for the whole dataset in the first case, and less precise in the second case.

Comment: test is a ndarray of shape (784,28000) with 784 being the number of pixels in the picture, and 28000 being the number of pictures in the dataset. and dividing both by training std makes sense now that I think about it. However, I'm still not sure why np.std  itself is wrong here.

Comment: I understand now that np.std() makes copies of the original input data when executing.However, I changed np.divide(test, np.std(test)) to np.divide(test, 255)) and I'm still getting the same error message.